# Svnstat for Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, statistics

Is there a utility for Mercurial which does something like svnstat does for subversion?

Answer (score 9):

The maillist post [found here](http://selenic.com/pipermail/mercurial/2010-April/031021.html) summarizes a few possibilties to generate reports for mercurial repositories.
The [mercurial activity extension](http://labs.freehackers.org/projects/hgactivity/wiki) mentioned there is under active development and looks promising.

Comment: The mercurial activity extension is great, but for Windows, don't overlook the link in the author's page for Windows users: http://blog.muhammada.li/how-to-chart-your-mercurial-commit-activity-w

Answer (score 7):

You can get a text graph showing the differences between two revisions

```
hg diff -r REV -r REV --stat
```

So that:

```
hg diff -r 0 -r tip --stat
```

shows info across the whole repo, but only on a file by file basis.

Alternately there are the [hg activity](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ActivityExtension), [hg chart](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ChartExtension), and [hg churn](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ChurnExtension) extensions.